# How to show all string examples in Swagger Doc model

Tags: swagger-ui

One of my model's in swagger returns a 'Status' property that could be one of multiple strings.

for example:

```
"Status" : {
    "type":"string",
    "example" : "'Completed' || 'Group Completed' || 'Errored' || 'Group Errored' || 'Ready' || 'Stopped By User' ||  'Initializing' || 'Queued' || 'Group Queued' ||  'Running' || 'Group Running' ||  'Stopping' || 'Group Stopping'"
               },
```

Doing it this way just looks really messy. What is the best way to display all these possible outcomes to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `enum` for this property:

```yaml
"Status" : {
  "type": "string",
  "enum": [
    "Completed",
    "Group Completed",
    "Errored",
    ...
  ]
}
```

The documentation renderer will display all enum values in the schema documentation.